@Asyncronuns annotation of ejb is not working in 2 production server out of 5 servers
I'm having one weird issue in the production server. I have total 5 application servers and 2 of them having issue with the asynchronous method of java.
If particular method has @Asyncronuns annotation and that method has been calling somewhere then it's not executing. Before it was working fine and all of sudden it having issue only in 2 servers. I have restarted the servers as well as db but it worked for 24 hours and then stop working.
I have checked all the server logs as well as application logs but did't find anything new or unusual.
There has been no deployment since 4 months even no new patch has been added in the application server since 1.5 years.
Server: JBOSS EAP 6.4
Java: 8
Also, I have used ExecutorService in my project and its working as expected but it's happening with @Asyncronuns only.
I have tried all the possible way putting logs but still not able to find the root cause of this issue. And fun thing is that It'll works for 24 hours then after it getting stopped working.
Code snippet for asynchronous method:
import javax.ejb.Asynchronous;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.infibeam.sapphire.beans.CallbackRequest;

@Stateless
public class ProcessCallBack {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProcessCallBack.class);

    @Inject
    CallbackRequestService callbackRequestService;

    @Asynchronous
    public void processAsyncCallbackRequest(CallbackRequest callbackRequest) {
        try {
            logger.debug("processAsyncCallbackRequest");
            callbackRequestService.processCallbackRequest(callbackRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("ERROR_ON_PROCESS_ASYNC_CALLBACK", e);
        }
    }

}

And it calling like this:
if(!callbackService.isCallbackRequestExist(callbackRequest.getRequestId())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

                    logger.debug("RMS_CALLBACK_DB_CHECK_POLL_"+i+"_"+ callbackRequest.getMsisdn());

                    if (callbackService.isCallbackRequestExist(callbackRequest.getRequestId())) {
                        processCallBack.processAsyncCallbackRequest(callbackRequest);
                        logger.debug("RMS_CALLBACK_PROCESS_SUCCESS_END_" + callbackRequest.getMsisdn());
                        return response;
                    }
                }
                response = responseGeneratorUtil.createResponseObject(404,
                        "Request ID not found: " + callbackRequest.getRequestId());

                logger.debug("RMS_CALLBACK_PROCESS_FAILURE_END_" + callbackRequest.getMsisdn());
                return response;

            } else {
                logger.info("CallbackResource : starting asnyc callback request : "+ callbackRequest);
                processCallBack.processAsyncCallbackRequest(callbackRequest);

                logger.debug("RMS_CALLBACK_PROCESS_SUCCESS_END_" + callbackRequest.getMsisdn());
                return response;
}

Pom.xml file:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-remote-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.55</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>


<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>

</build>

